# Add a column with a value as new entry on comparing value for current month and previous month using power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a column of months. I need to create a column with value as "new entry" if the current month holding is 0 and previous month holding is non zero.

Note: previous month is current month - 1

Comment: PowerBI doesn't have the concept of a "previous row" like Excel does.

Comment: You can show your sample data for better understanding. There must have a column for data Ordering so that you can climb up to previous row using the value.

Comment: what's your data source?